# Store values in a Java Collection

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, java-8

I want to store Id and Name into a Java Collection like this:

```
121 Name_1
332 Name_9
334 Name_e
..........
```

I can use a `HashMap` but I need to be able to extend the the collections with more values like this:

```
121 Name_1 1
332 Name_9 1
334 Name_e 3
............
```

Is there Java collection which can store these values without using Object?

Comment: You want to be able to extend all elements of your collections or only some of them?

Comment: If you need to be able to add extra values to each key, maybe you could use a map of lists?

Comment: @gla3dr can you show me some example, please?

Comment: There's almost no reason to not just create a class on your own to store the values you need.

Answer (score 6):

You should define a class for the data:

```
public class Whatever {
    private final String name;
    private final int someValue;

    public Whatever(String name, int someValue) {
        this.name = name;
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public in getSomeValue() { return someValue; }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Map<Integer, Whatever> theData = new HashMap<>();
theData.put(121, new Whatever("Name_1", 1));
```

(Of course, give the class and its fields meaningful names!)

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis on the `theData.put` statement. Otherwise, though, good answer.

Comment: @bcsb1001: Thanks, fixed. BTW, for these small errors, you can just edit the answer yourself (if you have enough rep).

Comment: I don't have enough rep (currently 614) but yeah, I will edit things like this when I have enough.

Answer (score 4):

you could think of using a library such as JSON Simple that offers flexibility with the number of fields a record has. here is an example taken from [this](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples) page:

> import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("name","foo");
obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
obj.put("nickname",null);
System.out.print(obj);
```

Comment: Is there s solution without third party libraries?

Comment: @user1285928 Have you tried `HashMap` whilst using ID as `Key` and name as `Value`?

Comment: Your example fails to show any advantage of this `JSONObject` over a plain `HashMap<String,Object>`. Further, you are performing unnecessary manual wrapping of values. There is no need to say `new Integer`, `new Double`, nor `new Boolean`. If you insist of doing it manually, you should learn about the `static` `valueOf` methods…

Answer (score 3):

what @gla3dr's comment mean is that `HashMap<String,List> sample = new HashMap<String,List>();`

then you put data in your list.

```
List myData = new ArrayList();

myData.add("121");
myData.add("Name_1");
myData.add("1");
```

then put it in the hashmap

```
sample.put("key",myData);
```

in this way you can still access the list

```
List myList = sample.get("key");
```

Comment: Of course, @TobiasBrandt's solution would still be best. This is sort of an ugly hack.

Comment: Also, you may have just done it to simplify the code for your answer, but raw types make me cringe.

Comment: yup TobiasBrandt's would be the best solution but @user1285928 ask what if he/she wanted to add more regardless of the number of values. that is what i understand from the question. that is why i just used this raw types.

Comment: I figure even just wrapping an implementation like this into its own class would work well. Sort of a combination of the two answers.

Comment: yes it is just the same implementation it is just that im using a list and TobiasBrandt is using a custom object. the only difference is that     it can have several values more without customizing the object because you just have to call `.add()` method but again it is kinda ugly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution for how you could store those:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Then you could create a list for the first value:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Name_1");
```

Then add that to the map along with the key:

```
map.put(121, list);
```

Then, when you want to extend one of the values, you can add to the list like so:

```
map.get(121).add("1");
```

Of course, this means that both the name and the second number are both stored as `String`s. If you want to store different types, you'll have to store them as `Object`s.

Answer (score 0):

Since you donot want to use object and only collection you can try the below code:-

```
        // Individual column names which can be extended
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        static final String KEY_NUM = "title";


        // Contains all the rows
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        // Contains column data in individual rows
        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map1.put(KEY_ID, 121);
        map1.put(KEY_NAME, "Name_1");
        map1.put(KEY_NUM, 1);

        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map2.put(KEY_ID, 334);
        map2.put(KEY_NAME, "Name_e");
        map2.put(KEY_NUM, 3);

        mapList.add(map1);
        mapList.add(map2);
```

Note that you can loop through the rows and create only one map reference variable instead of map1 and map2 and so on and assign for every row a new Hashmap object to it to make the code look more cleaner.